# How can I Improve speed of 2D Fourier Transform?

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I am trying to calculate this simple FT on a grid `{x,y}` but it tasks too long and gives me some error message even though the results are Ok. Are there other efficient ways to do this on MMA?

this is the Fourier transform

```
FT[xp_, yp_] := 
 1/\[Pi] NIntegrate[
   1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] Sqrt[ (x^2 + y^2)]]
     Exp[-I xp x] Exp[-I yp y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[
    1 - x^2]}]
```

I would like to calculate this on a square grid of `step=0.1` but it takes too long, here I used `step=1` and it takes `80 sec` is this reasonable?

```
step = 1.;
res = ParallelTable[{x1, y1, 
     Abs[FT[x1, y1] Conjugate[FT[x1, y1]]]}, {x1, -10., 10., 
     step}, {y1, -10., 10., step}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

---

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: 
   Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following:
    singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand,
    or WorkingPrecision too small.    

{81.4518, Null}
```

---

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[res, 1], PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

**Update#1**

the answer by @Daniel Lichtblau gives the output very fast but the results are not exactly the same as in the question. For example, if we set the plot range as follows we can see there is a wave-like profile at the base of the peak which is absent in the answer?

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[res, 1], PlotRange -> {0,0.03}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Here are the results from the answer

[image]

**Update#2**

As @yarchik mentioned the 2D integral in the question is not FT as I claimed which is a stupid mistake, the Best way to speed it up is by transforming it to polar coordinate, and results come in no time and looks like this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to sample your function on a regular grid and to apply `Fourier` (which applies FFT)?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, what do you mean by regular grid? isn't the same what I am doing?

Comment: Please, have a look at the documentation of `Fourier` first and see whether it suits your needs.

Comment: What you are computing is not the 2D Fourier transform. You introduce artifacts, such as the wave-like profile at the base of the peak, by integrating in a small disk-shape domain.  Also, it is known analytically that the Fourier transform of a gaussian peak is again a gaussian peak.  The best way to verify is to perform a transform twice. You should get the original peak in the case of FT.

Comment: @yarchik, that is a petty mistake I did to call that FT. Sorry for that. So how can I improve the speed of that integral, please?

Comment: You can speed it up by noticing the rotational symmetry and rewriting the integral in polar coordinates. The angular part is trivially done. The remaining 1D radial integral is easy to perform.

Comment: Thanks a lot @yarchik! that does the trick. Now I feel that the question was too trivial and would like to remove it:-)

Comment: No need to remove. Someone may find the whole discussion useful.

Answer (score 4):

This is more or less the suggestion from @HenrikSchumacher. At least that's the intent. Note that I make the step slightly offset from unity in order to avoid a singularity at the origin.

```
step = 1.01;
pts = Table[{x, y, 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)]]}, {x, -10., 10., 
    step}, {y, -10., 10., step}];
ft = Fourier[pts[[All, All, 3]]];
dims = Dimensions[ft]

(* Out[38]= {20, 20} *)
```

Now center the transform by rotating halfway. This pusts the DC component in the middle, modulo any off-by-one error in the code.

```
shift = Ceiling[dims[[1]]/2]; shiftedft = 
 RotateLeft[Map[RotateLeft[#, shift] &, ft], shift];
```

Recreate the proper coordinates.

```
newvals = 
  Table[{10*(i - shift)/shift, 10*(j - shift)/shift, 
    Abs[shiftedft[[i, j]]*Conjugate[shiftedft[[i, j]]]]}, {i, 
    dims[[1]]}, {j, dims[[2]]}];
```

Now we can (re)create the plot.

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[newvals, 1], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: that is very fast but did not give the desired results. Kindly see my update

Comment: @valarmorghulis, you should play with discretization parameters (see first Table[..] in Daniel's answer) to make the substructure more visible.

Comment: @Rom38, I did a mistake by calling that FT which is just an ordinary 2D integral, see my update 2